# R Pool Order of Connections

Tags: r, sql-server, oracle, jdbc, pool

I am using the R Pool package to connect to both SQL Server and Oracle databases within the same application. If I create the Oracle pool first I am unable to connect to SQL Server and get the following error:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(jc, "Unable to connect JDBC to ", url) :
```

but if I create the SQL Server pool first I have no problems and can subsequently connect to Oracle.

```
wd <- getwd()

driver1 = JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", classPath = file.path(wd,"mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar",":",wd,"jtds-1.3.1a.jar"))
connection1 = dbPool(drv=driver1, url=**, user=**, password=**, minsize=1, maxsize=5)

driver2 = JDBC("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", classPath = file.path(wd,"ojdbc6.jar"))
connection2 = dbPool(drv=driver2, url=**, user=**, password=**, minsize=1, maxsize=5)
```

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Try a newer version of the Oracle JDBC driver, ojdbc6.jar means it is far Java 6, and it means it is a relatively old version. Maybe upgrading to a newer version solves the issue.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for the suggestion! I just gave this a shot but unfortunately the problem is still there.